# rendering html to png (server-side)

Tags: html-rendering

I have a workflow model.
Internet Explorer doesn't support some features required for model editing functionality
(and regular user doesn't need it).

I want a read-only preview of my model.
Is it possible to server-side render my HTML to an image?

I would prefer offline solution to allow our system run in corporate LAN without access to internet.

Comment: My company was looking for a similar thing (HTML to PDF, actually) and couldn't find anything convenient and prepackaged. We had an idea to embed a stripped-down web browser and basically tell it to print the webpage in question. Ultimately, though, we decided it wasn't worth it for our (modest) needs.

Comment: @fennec, you should definetly evaluate http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf

Comment: on behalf of our product management people, thanks for your pointer. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are 'local' solutions:

- [`wkhtmltoimage` from the `wkhtmltopdf` package](https://wkhtmltopdf.org)

  does exactly its name says
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org)

  more advanced capabilities, like evaluating any js code in the page's context before rendering it to an image or pdf.

Comment: The wkhtmltoimage link above takes you to wkhtmltopdf, which doesn't appear to have the option to convert to pn. Only pdf and ps formats: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt. Help?

Comment: @spadeworkers, just download the package, it contains both `wkhtmltoimage` and `wkhtmltopdf` binaries

Comment: wkhtmltoimage is in C language.. 
i need such thing in php. any help pleaseee??

Comment: @saadk you can use `exec` or `system` command in php after installing `wkhtmltoimage` in server like `system('webkit2png http://www.google.com')`

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a java library called flyingsaucer (aka xhtmlrenderer). It has worked very well for me in the past.

Homepage:
http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer//

FAQ for generating an image:
http://pigeonholdings.com/projects/flyingsaucer/R8/doc/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_29