# Convert HTML to PNG or JPG in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rendering html to png (server-side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651173/rendering-html-to-png-server-side)

I have a DIV element with some images positioned within the DIV element. I want to make a JPG or a PNG file out of that, so people can save it for their Facebook timeline cover image. I found a LOT of scripts and tutorials, but nothing really fills my needs. This can't really be a very hard thing to do?

I already got my host to install iMagick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the positions via JavaScript (I guess you are using js to set the positions of the images in the div) and send them to a PHP-Script. With help of the [PHP GD manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) you can easily generate a png oder jpeg image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

[WKHTMLTOIMAGE](http://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: When i visit the link, it goes to WKHTMLTOPDF, is that correct? Also, how does it work?

Comment: there are README files my dear.

Answer (score 0):

I had to achieve the same thing, only for something else than Facebook and I used [webkit2png](https://github.com/paulhammond/webkit2png/blob/master/webkit2png)

I save the HTML code on a temporary HTML file, then I run the python webkit2png command on that temporary HTML file which converts it to PNG. It requires xvfb (apt-get install xvfb)

I then use the following command in PHP:

```
exec('xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1024x768x24" python webkit2png.py --log=/tmp/webkit2pnglog.log --output=' .$fullUploadPath . ' ' . $fullPath);
```

Where $fullUploadPath is the location of the target file and $fullPath is the location of the temporary HTML file.