# Generate a JPG image from a <table> in Classic ASP

Tags: image, asp-classic, export, jpeg

I have an ASP Classic page with a table. Is it possible to allow users to click in a button to export that table to a JPG file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily on the client side, and certainly not reliably enough that you could do it any browser. But checkout the following for some ideas!

- [Drawing DOM Content to a canvas](http://robert.ocallahan.org/2011/11/drawing-dom-content-to-canvas.html) - blog post outlining how to use SVG to render HTML inside an HTML5 canvas element.
- [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf) - StackOverflow post on obtaining an image from a canvas

What you'll probably have to do is render the HTML into an image on the server side. See following for ideas

- [rendering html to png (server-side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651173/rendering-html-to-png-server-side)

Comment: No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry to see you got a downvote, your question was clear enough. If you found this answer helpful, please upvote and/or mark as accepted.