# How to generate an image from a snippet of HTML code (as it is interpreted by the browser) on fly at runtime

Tags: java, html, jquery, screenshot

Can anyone guide how to generate image from input html code by Java API or Jquery library?
otherwise, how can I make a screenshot of a snippet of HTML code as it is interpreted by the browser?

for example :
if I have this HTML code :

```
<h1>Logo</h1><img src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-300.png">
```

I will generate an image which includes a screenshot of this code as it's interpreted by the browser

Comment: What environment are you trying to do this in? On a server or desktop using the Java JVM? Are you clear that Java and JavaScript are completely different languages? (I ask because you say "...by Java API or Jquery library...").

Comment: *"I will generate an image which includes a screenshot of this code as it's interpreted by the browser..."* ***Which*** browser? Although quite similar, each browser can render `h1` elements slightly differently. One browser can default to Times New Roman 18pt, another to Cambria 20pt, another might use FreeSerif 24pt. Some browsers (Lynx for example) run in text mode...

Comment: What does this have to do with `jquery-ajax`, exactly?

Comment: the important thing is to have a screenshot, regardless of the browser used

Comment: I add "jquery-ajax" to hint at "on fly at runtime"

Comment: @ user: That's meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [rendering html to png (server-side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651173/rendering-html-to-png-server-side)

And as you want a Java API, [Html2Image](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html) is the best solution for you.