# how to convert html code to png image using php

Tags: php

Is there a php script that allow to convert a html code to a png image.
The problem with GD library is that only convert text to image( and not html code )

Comment: Could you explain more? html *is* text.

Comment: @BeetleJuice I believe that he wants to take HTML, render it, and then save the rendered HTML as a png image.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651173/rendering-html-to-png-server-side ?

Comment: I think you might be better converting to PDF using something like http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ then you may have a better chance of converting PDF to an image.

Comment: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ this can convert HTML to PDF and Image both.

Comment: @BeetleJuice A better example is '<img src='mylittlepony.gif'>'. In text form, you see letters. In rendered form, you see a picture. I doubt he wants to see the text. He wants to see the image. Basically, he wants to automate a screen shot of a web page. He is likely making a web page thumbnail program.

Comment: @SheppardDigital If I convert to PDF , the convert PDF to PNG , the image will not be transparent

Comment: @BeetleJuice I want to rendrer the HTML with php(because I have inline css and call of font ) then convert it to transparent PNG

Answer (score 8):

There is no pure PHP solution to this.

Basically you've got two options:

1. Client-side rendering
   Use something like [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to render your image using javascript in the browser.
2. Server-side rendering
   Use a library like [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) which can be invoked by PHP to generate the image.
   Another server-side solution would be using [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) which can also run javascript before capturing the screen.

Comment: Client side rendering via html2canvas may face CORS issues which may prevent you from capturing images.

Comment: There's a new solution available: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#screenshots Will update my answer soon.