# convert html into jpg and send mail - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jpeg

I have an HTML which contains images and javascript charts. I want to convert that HTML into an image and send as an attachment through email.

Is it possible?

If yes, which library should I use for this task?

Comment: Take screenshot of your screen and then attach it in your email. For screenshot use Html2canvas. "https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas".

Comment: possibility duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651173/rendering-html-to-png-server-side

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721884/render-html-to-an-image

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but for that you need to use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).
Here is a php library i used for phantomjs.
http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/

Its pure php solution (using phantomjs browser) and is very easy to use. Just install this library through composer and that's it you should be good to go.

Note: This solution is valid if you want to take screenshot of your html page through its URL.

Hope it helps :-)